# Send Values of the Checkboxes Groups

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have interesting case. I have a page where I have groups of checkboxes created dynamically, I don't know their names before they're generated.

There might be name "type", "profile" and many more. There's possibility of displaying multiple groups at one time.

Do you have any idea how to send them via AJAX request in following format?
type=val1,val2
user=val1,val2

All data comes from database - it may depends on user selection, that's why I don't know their names.

Cheers!

Comment: Please can you explain in more detail with an example? What do you mean you don't know their names before they're generated? Would you like to be able to add labels to the checkboxes via AJAX?

Comment: Why would there be two values for a checkbox named "type"?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [jQuery.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [jQuery.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/), you'll have to iterate through your result array to make your string in your format and then send it to your AJAX Request.

Comment: Any ideas why it's sending multiple values, ex. type='1', type='2'?

Comment: Could you provide me some code to help you, the part of your html with your checkboxes and your javascript function to parse them. Thx